# Magento 2 - Clean SEO URL with attribute

Tags: magento2, attributes, layered-navigation, redirect, seo

**We run Magento 2 - 2.1.6**

Question:

If I create a link based on layered navigation attributes **(storeurl: /clothes?cat=1029&gender=124)** for example.

We get a lot of errors regarding **Google Search Console.**

I've tried to create a redirect but this doesn't work.

I would like to see something like this **(storeurl: /clothes/rsl/ladies)**

I know this is possible I just don't know how?
Can someone please help me with my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yep magento 1 and 2 is limited at this sort of thing

Is possible but you will need an extension. For example:

https://www.manadev.com/magento-extensions/magento-2-layered-navigation